# Use cases dependent on another use case

Tags: uml, diagram, use-case

How to present on the diagram of use cases that

- before any activity an actor needs to be logged in into the system?
- e.g Use case "Display information about an employee" uses server and the another use case ("Search the employee in the database")?

Is my use case diagram correct?

[image: Uce Case Diagram]

Comment: To complement on the other answers: you're doing it (completely) wrong.

Comment: @GeertBellekens, Yes, now I know it was wrong :) I posted this below: http://imgur.com/a/3jzHe

Comment: Looks a lot better already, although I would split that into 4 or 5 different diagrams.

Comment: One diagram = one actor?

Comment: BTW I've asked the same question on another discuss group (in my native language) and they say, that on use case diagram there mustn't be e.g. server and use cases for server, because server is a part of the system. So I remove it from diagram.

Answer (score 3):

You need to set pre-condition constraints for UCs telling `{ user must be logged on}`.

Your UC diagram start resembling a spider's web (and is hardly recognizable). A good indicator that your design went wrong somewhere. Look at the single UCs and ask yourself: does this represent added value for the actor? If the answer is yes, you're fine.

After some zoom I see "Employee management", "Account management" and others that simply do not name UCs meaningful (they are likely processes). Use verb-substantive. And keep above question in mind.

Answer (score 2):

A quick google indicates that use case preconditions are a useful way to represent the requirement that a user be logged in first.  However, preconditions can clutter the UC diagram with text and possibly restrict the number of use cases on a particular diagram.  I suggest creating a new actor that is an "authenticated user".  This differentiates the actor from a user that has not yet logged in and allows clear representation of the use cases available to each.

Comment: @foxbuur: Looks good enough to submit for review to peers, boss, or teacher.